# Grammar for are/is

Tags: verbs

All the Kennedy family is grateful for your support.

Or
All the Kennedy family are grateful for your support.

Comment: I think your problem is having 'all'. It sounds odd. Just 'the Kennedy family is grateful ...' is fine.